# jQuery plugins - accessing element from the options

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

Most jQuery plugins have options like this one for example (cycle):

```
 $("ul").cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    startingSlide: 1,
    speed: 500,
    pause: true});
```

The plugin will do his thing on all elements with the class/ID you specify, in this case all `<UL>` elements.
How can I access this `<UL>`'s child elements from within one of these options.

For example `startingSlide` only accepts numbers, and I want to pass a function that returns a number, instead of just a number.

The problem is that within that function I don't know how to access the **current** `<UL>` the plugin is working with (not all ULs)

Comment: So you want to modify the cycle plugin to allow `startingSlide` to be a callback function?

Comment: Yes, something like that I guess :)
Do I need to modify the plugins code? This will rise problems with maintainace (updates)

Comment: Why do you need to pass in a function?  Since it's a starting variable, why not just call that function, e.g. `startingSlide: getStartNumber()` where `function getStartNumber()` returns the int you want?  Or, is the example option not really the one you're after, if that's the case, can you clarify a bit?

Comment: nevermind, I found a solution: use jQuery('ul').each() and inside it get the ID of the current ul and add cycle() on it. I can get the number I want inside each() as well.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin works only on the wrapped set that you specify eg `$("ul")`, if you want to something to happen to children of `ul`, you will have to specify that instead `$("ul > li")`. So the plugin will do its job on the wrapped set/selector you specify to it.